# What does the question in the tour have unnecessary thanks in it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Why does the [example question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/graphic-music-visualizer-without-after-effects) on the [tour](https://video.stackexchange.com/tour) page have unnecessary thanks in it?

[image: Question With Unnecessary Thanks]

Should this be removed from the example question, as it seem to me that this is [discouraged](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/243/16850)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It additionally had a pretty non-ideal tag on it for after-effects even though it is looking for alternatives, not actually about after effects.  I cleaned that up, but looks like there may be some caching involved.  I believe the question may have been picked at random when they put the new tour in.  I wasn't even aware of the feature showing it with an actual question, though I see we can change the question if we feel like another question would be a better sample.

Answer (score 3):

I agree and [suggested an edit](https://video.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10466) to that effect.